# Laravel Scout Elastic Search - Index not found

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-scout

I am facing a weird issue with elasticsearch.
I am working on a Laravel project and need to integrate elastic search with it.
I am using https://github.com/babenkoivan/scout-elasticsearch-driver along with Laravel Scout.
Initially everything worked fine and I was also able to search. When it worked fine, I wanted to drop my index and reindex everything from scratch. But after that when I ran my seeder, I got an "Index not found exception". Then to test it I created index and type. eg: **TestIndex/department**
After that the seeder ran fine and I didn't get the "index not found exception". However, it didn't use the index which I created. It created a new index of the form **"TestIndex_write/department"**

Can someone please explain what am I doing wrong? why is new index with a different name being created automatically?

I am using ElasticSearch > 6.0

Answer (score 1):

Although 2 months past,try update  index configurator :

> php artisan elastic:update-index App\MyIndexConfigurator

Comment: This fixed it for me, however, you have to escape the \ so actually this should be:

php artisan elastic:update-index App\\MyIndexConfigurator